# error deploy django app in pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

```
2021-04-29 18:44:38,475: ***************************************************
2021-04-29 18:44:38,475: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2021-04-29 18:44:38,475: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2021-04-29 18:44:38,475: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2021-04-29 18:44:38,475: ***************************************************
2021-04-29 18:44:39,075: Error running WSGI application
2021-04-29 18:44:39,076: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
2021-04-29 18:44:39,076:   File "/var/www/paulosix_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 29, in <module>
2021-04-29 18:44:39,076:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2021-04-29 18:44:39,076: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077:   File "/home/paulosix/.virtualenvs/singe/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077:   File "/home/paulosix/.virtualenvs/singe/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077:   File "/home/paulosix/.virtualenvs/singe/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077:     self._setup(name)
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077:   File "/home/paulosix/.virtualenvs/singe/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2021-04-29 18:44:39,077: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078:   File "/home/paulosix/.virtualenvs/singe/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078:   File "/home/paulosix/djangoSIGE/djangosige/configs/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078:     from .settings import *
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078:   File "/home/paulosix/djangoSIGE/djangosige/configs/settings.py", line 19, in <module>
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078:     ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('paulosix.pythonanywhere.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1')
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078:   File "/home/paulosix/.virtualenvs/singe/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 197, in __call__
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078:     return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
2021-04-29 18:44:39,078: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,079:   File "/home/paulosix/.virtualenvs/singe/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 85, in __call__
2021-04-29 18:44:39,079:     return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
2021-04-29 18:44:39,079: 
2021-04-29 18:44:39,079:   File "/home/paulosix/.virtualenvs/singe/lib/python3.8/site-packages/decouple.py", line 79, in get
2021-04-29 18:44:39,079:     return cast(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are passing wrong arguments to the `config` call that is expected to return `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list. According to `python-decouple` [docs](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/#understanding-the-cast-argument) the correct call to `config` should look like that:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = config(
    'ALLOWED_HOSTS', 
    default=['paulosix.pythonanywhere.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1'], 
    cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(',')]
)
```

There is a question what do you have in your `.env` file where `python-decouple` is looking for the value of `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in the first place.